# get value for api calling from other functions state REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So far I am calling an api in componentDidMount() and set it to select option. 
also call another conditional api from user input. 
But Problem is it is calling the api non stop.

```
**getRates(){
    const base = this.handlePrint(this.state.value);
    fetch(`https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latest?base=${base}`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data =>{
           this.setState({
               rate: data.rates,
           })
            console.log(data.rates)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}**
```

And my console screen shot:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OSZW.png)

I just need one time api call based on user input.

full code: https://codeshare.io/5MwXzq

I think there is a problem with the state but I am new in reactjs and could not understand how to solve that.
Anyone can help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening not because of anything in `componentDidMount()`

Based on the code you shared on `codeshare.io`, you're calling `getRates()` function in your `render()` method. Also, you're setting the state using `setState` within the `getRates` method. This causes a re-render, calling `render()` again, and so you get the infinite loop of calls.

Remove the call to `getRates()` from your `render` method and it'll work.

EDIT:

Since there were small changes but strewn across your code to get it to work, I've modified your class and posting it here:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currencies: [],
      value: "?",
      base: "?",
      input: "?",
      rate: 0
    };
    this.getRates = this.getRates.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePrint = this.handlePrint.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latest?symbols=USD,GBP,AUD,JPY")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        const currencies = [];
        currencies.push(
          data.base,
          ...Object.entries(data.rates).map(rates => rates[0])
        );

        this.setState({
          currencies
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  getRates() {
    const base = this.handlePrint();
   console.log(this.state); fetch(`https://exchangeratesapi.io/api/latest?base=${base}`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          rate: data.rates
        });
        console.log(data.rates);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  //Dropdown
  DropDown = function(list) {
    return <option value={list}>{list}</option>;
  };

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  handlePrint() {
    console.log(this.state)
    if (this.state.value) {
      return this.state.value;
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { currencies } = this.state;
   // const input = this.getRates();

    return (
      <div>
        <span>SELECT your Base: </span>
        <select autoFocus onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option inputcurrency={currencies} selected data-default>
            SELECT BASE
          </option>
          {currencies.map(this.DropDown)}
        </select>
        <button onClick={this.getRates}>GET RAtes</button>
        <p>selected base:{this.handlePrint()} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The changes are:
1. Bound `getRates()` method in the constructor
2. Removed the call to `getRates()` in render start
3. Removed unnecessary items passed to `handlePrint`
4. Changed the button `onClick` to point to `getRates`

Comment: But I need to call this getRates() method from <button/> from render